# SVG not showing anything on browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

Hi I have just started learning js and I am facing some issues.My following code is not showing anything,I am trying to create a barplot here from a csv file,the code is running fine,bootstrap library is also working properly,however when i run it only svg part is not visibe,I am using tomcat 8.0 server on eclipse IDE any help is much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Basic Bootstrap Template</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type = "text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v2.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<h1>Clinical Data Analysis</h1>
<p>Global Performance</p> 
</div>
<svg class="chart" width="40" height="40"></svg>
<p>Global Performance</p> 
<script>


var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = 200,
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin;


var xScale = d3.scaleBand().range ([0, width]).padding(0.4),
    yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range ([height, 0]);

var g = svg.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + 100 + "," + 100 + ")");

d3.csv("XYZ.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }

    xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.year; }));
    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

    g.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

    g.append("g")
     .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(function(d){
         return "$" + d;
     }).ticks(10))
     .append("text")
     .attr("y", 6)
     .attr("dy", "0.71em")
     .attr("text-anchor", "end")
     .text("value");
});
</script>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"> 
</svg> 
</body>
</html>
```

Code is running but bar plot is not showing

Comment: The `svg` element does not exist at the time your script runs. Put your script in a separate file and give its script tag the `defer` attribute.

Comment: Sorry,but can you please elaborate,I really dont know much about it.Thanks in advance

Comment: Save the script to a separate file and then link it, eg with `<script src="myscript.js" defer>`. You can also move the script tag to the end of the body instead, but that's pretty inelegant. Another solution is to wrap the whole script in a DOMContentLoaded listener.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: I would've thought that selecting an element that did not exist would throw an error. Do you see an error now?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: d3.scaleBand is not a function
    at (index):27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues, one is you are using a d3 version that isn't compliant with your code, and two, your dimensions need to be modified.

The first issue is that you are using an old version(s) of d3:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v2.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

But using d3v4 namespace:

```
yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range ([height, 0]);
```

*for example, D3v3 uses d3.scale.linear()*

Since the scales in d3v3 are all properties of d3.scale, there is no property or function of the d3 library located at `d3.scaleBand` or `d3.scaleLinear`, and consequently you see the error you are getting. D3v4 changed this design pattern.

So, let's use d3v4, that solves the first issue.

---

Second, your dimensions need to be modified. You have an svg that is 40x40:

```
<svg class="chart" width="40" height="40"></svg>
```

But you have a margin of 200 (or 100 on each side), naturally nothing appears inside the visible portion of the svg. You are actually specifing a negative height and width here:

```
width = svg.attr("width") - margin,    // width = 40 - 200
height = svg.attr("height") - margin;  // height = 40 - 200
```

Instead, we can increase the svg to 500,500 (for example) and set the margin to something more reasonable like 40 pixels, then we should see your axes as expected:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = 40,
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin*2,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin*2;

var xScale = d3.scaleBand().range ([0, width]).padding(0.4),
    yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range ([height, 0]);

var g = svg.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")");


var data = [
 {year: 2000, value: 100},
 {year: 2001, value: 200},
 {year: 2002, value: 300},
 {year: 2003, value: 400},
 {year: 2004, value: 200},
 {year: 2005, value: 100},
];

    xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.year; }));
    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

    g.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height) + ")")
     .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

    g.append("g")
     .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(function(d){
         return "$" + d;
     }).ticks(10))
     .append("text")
     .attr("y", 6)
     .attr("dy", "0.71em")
     .attr("text-anchor", "end")
     .text("value");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<h1>Clinical Data Analysis</h1>
<p>Global Performance</p> 
</div>
<svg class="chart" width="500" height="500"></svg>
<p>Global Performance</p>
```

And here is [a bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/886546389ca7dea2c4fafbe2055cfe3a/) demonstrating it.

*I added some dummy data that I embedded directly. I also didn't add a line as you didn't include code for that, so it is just the axes*

Comment: It might be worth also pointing out the third error as mentioned in the comments, which is the positioning of the script and the availability of the DOM.

Comment: Thank you so much ,it really helped

Comment: @AkshaySharma, I just noticed that you have two svg's in the document, one below the script and one above. If there was just one svg, and it was below the script, the script will run before the svg is added to the DOM and nothing will be added to the SVG (the commenters on the question likely only saw the svg tag on the bottom, I only saw the one on top). If both svgs were in the DOM (and the script is below the svg tags), d3.select will only select the first svg on the page. Hope that helps a bit further.